# Value of online presence for PhD Admits. (FALL 2022 CS USA)

Tags: graduate-admissions

With LinkedIn, Research Gate and Twitter (there might be others I am not aware of), many people have managed to make an online presence for themselves through various activities.

**Does this in any way affect a PhD admit for the indiviual?**

Please assume the presence to be based on technical activities and all in a positive notion.

Comment: I've no clue about the answer but very much hope it is a clear No.

Comment: Related: [Is web-presence important for researchers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/616/68109)

Comment: I don't think this answer my question. I am an undergrad looking for PhD programs. I'm sure there should be some difference when compared to a researcher.

Comment: If you've done any scholarly work, then that could make a positive impression. I'd recommend that you make it available online and easy to find if possible. That is, if someone types in your name and the title of your work into Google, they can immediately access a copy **with no login required**.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the suggestion. I normally just attach my google scholar link everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most schools have an application.  Your admission is based on the contents of the application.

I can't imagine a school that would then spend the extra time to formalize an additional search of information not supplied in the application to bolster the application.  Perhaps an individual might do so, but generally this is discouraged by any competent staff because there's always the initial problem of "do we have the right person in the first place?" and then there's the other issue of "how do we disqualify someone based on information not in their application?"

If the information supports your admissions, it shouldn't be referenced by proxy.  Put it in the application and the supporting materials requested by the school.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: @Aymuos good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much !!